# jquery UI connected sortable (from ul to div)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 sortables. One applied to a  and one to a 
I used 'connectWith' on both and I can't seem to be able to drag from the  to the 
Here is a jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/P9dDY/

Comment: probably the items should be wrapped within <ul> as a list instead in div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put some of your style code in the head and deleted it from the body like so...

```
<style type="text/css">
#div-parent {width:800px; height:30px;}
#div-parent div {width:90px; height:30px; float:left; display:block;}
</style>
```

Now it seems to work, see http://jsfiddle.net/P9dDY/2/

Comment: Thanks  it seems my problem was that the div did not have height set